# X won't start without 3 or 4 Ctrl-Cs

Tags: linux, linux-mint, x

For some strange reason I have to input Ctrl-C (usually) three times (sometimes four) after running `startx` in order to get cinnamon to start. This is the same as with dwm or i3.
Partial demonstration with `ttyrec`/`ttyplay`: https://www.sendspace.com/file/low2h7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing these error messages:

```
xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/jacob/.Xauthority
xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/jacob/.Xauthority
```

You can try and reproduce the problem by running `xauth list` on the command line. If it produces the same message, you probably have a stale lock file. (If this command runs without problems, your system-wide `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` file might be trying to be overly clever; but I think that is the less likely option.)

Apparently the lock file might be named `/home/jacob/.Xauthority-c`. Run `ls -ld /home/jacob/.Xauthority-c /home/jacob` to see if it has different ownership or some other permission problem. This command will also list the ownership and permissions of your home directory: verify that it has the correct ownership too.

If the `.Xauthority-c` file is owned by you, you can run `xauth` with a permission to break any stale locks:

```
xauth -b list
```

If it runs successfully, the stale lock should automatically get removed. Test with running `xauth list` again; it should now run successfully without the `-b` option.

Or you could just delete both the lock file and the `.Xauthority` file itself; it will be automatically re-generated the next time you start a X session. Just be aware that if you have other simultaneous X sessions with the same user account (either local or remote ones), removing the `.Xauthority` file will cause problems for them.